# How to get correct Uri/String and convert to byteString?

Tags: android, kotlin, byte

That's my list with Strings.

```
[content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16538, 
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16535, 
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16537, 
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.myapp/myapp/2023-08-15-22-51-59-754.jpg]
```

I am creating auto attachments adding and sending emails.
Everything works fine with `CameraView`, where my output before converting is:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.myapp/myapp/2023-08-15-22-51-59-754.jpg
```

but I have problem with this output, when I use `PhotoPicker`, I can launch it to `Image` component, but I cannot apply it to attachment as `byte` converted to `string`.

that's my code when I use correct String:

```
                        val imageUrl = URL("file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.myapp/myapp/2023-08-15-22-51-59-754.jpg")
                        val imageStream = imageUrl.openStream()
                        val imageContent = imageStream.readBytes()

                    // To Base 64
                        val imageBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageContent)

                        val attachment =
                            "{\"content\": \"$imageBase64\",\"filename\": \"IMAGE_${currentDate}_$index.jpg\",\"type\": \"image/jpeg\",\"disposition\": \"attachment\"}"
```

and that's my approach when I try to convert content.

```
val imageString = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16537"
                        val imageStream = imageString.byteInputStream()
                        val imageContent: ByteArray = imageStream.readBytes()
                        val imageBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageContent)

                        val attachment =
                            "{\"content\": \"$imageBase64\",\"filename\": \"IMAGE_${currentDate}_$index.jpg\",\"type\": \"image/jpeg\",\"disposition\": \"attachment\"}"
```

I have found something like finding realPath, but it does not work.

```
private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentUri: Uri, context: Context): String? {
    val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    val loader = CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null)
    val cursor: Cursor = loader.loadInBackground()
    val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    val result = cursor.getString(column_index)
    cursor.close()
    return result
}
```

But output is 1kB file with no image in it, so tried different approaches but right know I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that's my code when I use correct String:

Here, you are opening an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

> and that's my approach when I try to convert content

No, it is not. Here, you are turning *the `Uri` itself* (its characters, like `c` and `o` and `n` and `t` and `e` and `n` and `t`) into a stream.

You need to use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. What is nice is that you can use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` for both `file://` and `content://` `Uri` values.